# How to display adsense only when my website is not enclosed in an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, adsense

I have a website which also is a canvas app on Facebook. According to FB policies I cannot show Adsense ads on the canvas page. Also according to Google Adsense  policies I cannot show Adsense in iFrames which is used by FB to show my site as a canvas app. And my site uses Adsense to monetize.

I need a simple solution to render my Adsense ads only when my site is not iframed either as a canvas app or by any other means.

I tried using jquery and did the following

```
if (window==window.top) {
    $.getScript("show_ads.js");
}
```

but that doesn't render the ads in any case. The show_ads.js is the Adsense ad rendering script as provided by Google.

Am looking for a different approach to solving this problem.

Comment: Have you tried `window.parent == null`? That would mean you are not in an iframe.

Comment: @Diego — `window.parent` will never be `null`. In the top level frame, `window.parent == window` … which is more or less what is being checked for in the question.

Comment: I suspect  your problem is that `$.getScript("show_ads.js");` doesn't work, but we can't see the code in *show_ads.js*.

Comment: show_ads.js is what is executed in Google adsense script to render the Ads. If you take a Google Adsense script, it has two parts to it. First part defines the ad unit and the second part (always show_ads.js) renders it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try

    var isInIframe = (window.parent !=null && window.location != window.parent.location) ? true : false;
        if (!isInIframe )
         loadScript("http://your.cdn.com/show_ads.js");
```

[reference](http://www.jquery4u.com/snippets/jquery-check-window-iframe/)

Try this to load a js file:

```
function loadScript(url, callback){

    var script = document.createElement("script")
    script.type = "text/javascript";

    if (script.readyState){  //IE
        script.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (script.readyState == "loaded" ||
                    script.readyState == "complete"){
                script.onreadystatechange = null;
                callback();
            }
        };
    } else {  //Others
        script.onload = function(){
            callback();
        };
    }

    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: If the page is framed by a different origin, that will throw an exception and the script will terminate. If it does anything after testing to see if adverts should be included, then that will break.

Comment: Why would substituting `parent` for `top` or adding `location` help with the problem anyway?

Comment: Can you use a css selector to hide it when it is in an iframe? example, without knowing your actual clases and id's: normal - .adsense{display: block;} on FB - #FB .adsense{display: none;}

Comment: @Quentin If it throws an exception, that can be caught and taken as "Yes, we're in an iframe, don't show adsense". So, it can work.

Comment: @DrCord That would fix the FB side, but it would still be against the adsense TOS due to the invalid impression.

Comment: @KevinB — Yes, but (a) this code doesn't catch it and (b) you can avoid it by not testing `location`

Comment: @cristelo Sorry, that doesn't solve it. The problem seems to be in how jquery is getting the adsense show_ads.js and executing it. Though jquery does it, adsense doesn't render. Need a different approach.